# Yoast plugin is not showing meta description and meta keyword

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, yoast

I am a newbie and learning new things every now and then. I recently set up Yoast on my WordPress website and I put title, focus keyword, and meta description for every single page of my website manually in Yoast widget. This shows up under the page but unfortunately the meta description and keywords is not appear on the page source.

In fact throughout the website same title and description is displayed. Is there any additional configuration required after installation of Yoast in header.php or somewhere in files?

Comment: Is your theme using `wp_title()` and `wp_head()` or is <title> hardcoded in your template?

Answer (score 1):

You can add code to functions.php for showing focus keywords as meta-keywords in  section of the page.

```
function set_head_keywords() {
    $id = get_the_ID();
    if (!$id) return;
    $meta = get_post_meta( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', true );
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$meta.'" />';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'set_head_keywords' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from **Yoast seo plugin** is stated below:

We’ve removed the meta keywords feature in Yoast SEO from version 6.3. Meta keywords haven’t had a use for a long time, so their removal from our plugin has been long overdue.

*Reference:* https://kb.yoast.com/kb/meta-keywords-yoast-seo/

**Google:**
Google does not use the keywords meta tag in web ranking.

*Reference:* https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

**Yahoo!** Announced they no longer use the meta keywords tag anymore either.

**Bing:**
On 2014: Today, it’s pretty clear the meta keyword tag is dead in terms of SEO value. Sure, it might have value for contextual ad systems or serve as a signal to ‘bots plying the web looking for topics to target, but as far as search goes, that tag flat lined years ago as a booster.

*Reference:* https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2014/10/03/blame-the-meta-keyword-tag